# Sometimes need to turn printer on/off to process print queue?

Tags: printer, network-printer

I've got a rather annoying problem. Our laser printer at work (HP CP3525) will only print one document at a time. After that, it needs to be turned on/off to process the next document in the queue. What could be happening?

The printer has already been replaced [not as an attempt to resolve this problem, for an uneconomical repair] and the problem persists. The printer is used by users on a LAN of 5-10 people. All drivers are up-to-date as far as I know.

Where should I look next?

Comment: Check Spooler Settings on Printserver/Clients. Check it bidirectional Setting is activated.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. The checkbox for me to enable the bidirectional setting is grayed out. I've tried reinstalling the driver for the printer etc as the internet says to solve that problem but having no luck. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you using an Print server? If yes which version? Normaly when the checkbox is grayed out it means that the driver is not fully supported for that OS.

Comment: Nope, no print server. I'm on Windows 7, the driver is listed on HP's website as supporting my OS. The documentation suggests that the printer does support bidirectional too, so I'm a little perplexed...

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve the problem by installing the Windows PostScript UDP from HP's website rather than the one it recommended/Windows 7 installed automatically. The driver basically takes print management away from Windows and works great.

Thanks to Patrick all the same, his comment may help someone else with my problem.